# Java: method from another class can't be resolved

Tags: java

I am new to java. I have created an object of a class but when I try and access a method from the object, it says it cant be resolved. The 2 classes are below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class setup {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String goverment;
    int happyness;
    double money;
    int population = 1000000;


    public setup() {
    }

    public void statsSetup() {
        System.out.println("Choose a goverment: 1. democracy 2. monarchy 3. dictatorship");
        goverment = input.nextLine();

        if (goverment.equals("1"))
        {
            happyness = 75;
            money = 250000.0;

        }
        else if (goverment.equals("2"))
        {
            happyness = 50;
            money = 500000.0;
        }
        else if (goverment.equals("3"))
        {
            happyness = 25;
            money = 750000.0;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ENTER A VALID VALUE");
        }
    }

    public int getHappyness() {
        return happyness;
    }

    public double getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gameLoop  {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int turn = 0;

    public gameLoop() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setup setupGov = new setup();
    }

    public void loop() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Turn: "+turn);
            ***System.out.println("happyness: " + setupGov.getHappyness() + " money: £" + setupGov.getMoney() + " population: " + setupGov.getPopulation());***
            input.nextLine();
            turn++;
        }
    }
}
```

the error occurs in the gameLoop class when I try and print the variables from the setup class

Comment: Because you are creating a local variable in `main` which is not passed to your `loop` function?

Comment: Hint for the next time: you want us to spend our time to help you; so you please spend the few minutes it takes to properly format/indent **all** of your code. Then: do not overtag. Then: please read about java coding conventions. Class names start Uppercase, **always**.

Comment: You never called `loop()` anyways.

Answer (score 2):

move `setup setupGov = new setup();` outside the `main` function, put it right under `static int turn = 0;`

And I strongly suggest that you find a good programming basics course, there is many out there